# How to send an array of object having file with ajax to asp.net MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

[image: Data uploader grid]

I've been trying to send multiple rows with a single file in each row(please see the above image) to my MVC controller with ajax. JavaScript code-

```
var formData = new FormData();
$('#assFileTable tbody tr').each(function (index, item) {
    var tr = $(this);
    var description = tr.find('.dTableDescription').val();
    var docType = tr.find('.dTableDocType').val();
    var attachment = $('#row-' + index + '-Attachment').get(0).files[0];

    var assoFile = {
        Description: description,
        DocTypeId: docType,
        Attachment: attachment
    };
    formData.append('assoFiles', assoFile);
});

var request = new Request('/Setting/SaveAssociatedFiles/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
});
fetch(request).then(response => console.log(response.json()));
```

Controller Method-

```
public ActionResult SaveAssociatedFiles(List<TaskAssociatedFileViewModel> assoFiles)
{            
}
```

Model-

```
public class TaskAssociatedFileViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int DocTypeId { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method is invoked but getting null instead of sent data. Am I missing anything or I've to do different things?

Comment: Try it without the file/attachment property in the model to narrow down that it is definitely just the files causing the problem.

Comment: `formData.append('assoFiles'`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append *append() will append the new value onto the end of the existing set of values.* - however your MVC controller has no way to know this.

Comment: Given the above - try with just one row (without file) - if that works but doesn't work with multiple (without files) then your problem is `formData.append` which is putting all your values in the same key.   The MVC controller is expecting an *array* of values.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood, you are just sending single last row of the table in `assoFiles` key

```
var formData = new FormData();
let allDataArray = [];
    $('#assFileTable tbody tr').each(function (index, item) {
        var tr = $(this);
        var description = $(this).find('.dTableDescription').val();
        var docType = $(this).find('.dTableDocType').val();
        var attachment = $('#row-' + index + '-Attachment').get(0).files[0];

        var assoFile = {
            Description: description,
            DocTypeId: docType,
            Attachment: attachment
        };
        allDataArray.push(assoFile)

    });
    formData.append('assoFiles', allDataArray);
    var request = new Request('/Setting/SaveAssociatedFiles/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
    });
    fetch(request).then(response => console.log(response.json()));
```

1. Create a blank array

   let allData = []
2. Append `assoFile` in formData blank array

   allData.push(assoFile)
3. `formData.append('assoFiles', allData);`

Comment: Question: if this was the case then wouldn't OP get one row of data (the last one) in their controller?  Not null.  This certainly does seem to be an issue, perhaps it will be the next issue that OP gets.

Comment: Although I think it would be more clear with the html if he post but i find issue with var docType = tr.find('.dTableDocType').val(); as well. he is looping the table row and then I believe their is a class name dTableDocType which is input field then  tr.find('.dTableDocType').val(); value will be null or blank based on his condition. Check once.

Comment: Not sure about your last comment as the screenshot shows doc type as a `select` - so `tr.find(".dTableDocType").val()` will be the `value=` or the text of the selected option.

Comment: OK yes , sorry var tr = $(this); that's fine. missed it.

Comment: @souravsatyam I tried your solution. But I'm still getting "count 0" in my controller method. Actually, is it possible to pass an array with FormData?

Comment: @ChanchalZoarder yes! you can pass array in form data . In the above case you can retrieve the value using  `assoFiles` key.